# What is the longest train ride starting in the EU, now that Sibirjak is discontinued?

Tags: trains, europe

Sadly, the [Sibirjak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sibirjak) train service that connected Berlin directly to destinations as far away as Novosibirsk (5,130 km), no longer operates.  Now that Sibirjak is discontinued, what is the longest direct scheduled passenger train departing from the EU?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_train_services#Europe), this is either [Nice-Moscow](http://moscow-paris.ru/moscow_nice_en.html) line (3315 km), closely followed by Paris-Moscow (3217 km).

I would have thought that the Venice Simplon Express on the route [Prague-London](https://www.belmond.com/web/vsoe/journeys/4_176634.jsp?__utma=110027138.1886915254.1400878862.1400878862.1400878862.1&__utmb=110027138.6.10.1400878862&__utmc=110027138&__utmx=-&__utmz=110027138.1400878862.1.1.utmcsr=%28direct%29%7Cutmccn=%28direct%29%7Cutmcmd=%28none%29&__utmv=-&__utmk=255764936) or the [Paris-Istanbul](https://www.belmond.com/web/vsoe/journeys/4_169630.jsp?__utma=110027138.1886915254.1400878862.1400878862.1400878862.1&__utmb=110027138.2.10.1400878862&__utmc=110027138&__utmx=-&__utmz=110027138.1400878862.1.1.utmcsr=%28direct%29%7Cutmccn=%28direct%29%7Cutmcmd=%28none%29&__utmv=-&__utmk=259509578) route would be a good candidate too, but I can't really find the distances. A google maps route plan using a car suggest that both are shorter than the above, but obviously this will depend on the exact route taken.

Comment: Ah, yes.  The Paris-Istanbul train is a bit too fancy for what I had in mind (more like a super-de-luxe train than a "normal" train), but Nice-Moscow offers more regular alternatives.